# .net 4.8 IdentityModel The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: .net-4.8, identitymodel

I have a solution with two project (.net 4.8)

1. WebAPI
2. Class library

In my web api I am using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation and there is a dependency with IdentityModel 1.9.2.

In Class library I added IdentityModel 4.4.0 to get the ClientCredentialsToken from IDServer.

Class library added as a reference to Webapi. During the run time I am getting error

> Could not load file or assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=4.4.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f' or one of its
> dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> match the assembly reference.

Any clue to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.